# Embedding Paypal Digital Goods with Express checkout in Flash not working

Tags: flash, paypal, express-checkout

I am attempting to integrate the Paypal digital goods with express checkout into my flash application. I am using this documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingDigitalGoodsInFlash/

First I am just trying to call the function manually to see if it triggers the pop-up. It does not work - all I get is the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null (dg.js:13)**

My very basic code is as follows (generated by PayPal Digital Goods - PHP Library for PayPal Digital Goods with Express Checkout) by Leonard's Ego Pty. Ltd:

```
<script src ="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow();
    dg.startFlow('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC-9TR342235S986371E');
</script>
```

That's all that is on the html page. I was expecting the paypal div to pop up.

Does anyone know the proper code required for this to work? The flash example on the paypal site doesn't say much.

I could answer my own question if there was some reference or documentation for this dg.js javascript class. But after some thorough google searching, I've found nothing. Does anyone have a link to some documentation for this? https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js

Thanks so much!

**Update:** The Javascript documentation is in fact missing. This link [JavaScript Functions For Digital Goods Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/#id10A5B0I0SHS) redirects to nothing on the documentation page. Anyone from PayPal scours this forum? Anyone know who I should contact regarding this omission?

Answer (score 0):

I answered both of my own questions:

1) Well so it ended up being a stupid javascript error, not related to Paypal at all. I needed to put the dg.startFlow() inside a window.onload function. (Note this is auto generated from php)

```
<script src ="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow();
    var merchantUrl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC-9TR342235S986371E';

    window.onload = function()
    {
        dg.startFlow(merchantUrl);
    }
</script>
```

2) A better google search found this PDF from 2010, which does in fact have a reference of the functions one can call in the JavaScript dg class: [PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://merchant.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/merchant/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide_DGEnt.pdf). The Javascript reference is on pg 24 - 25.

Hope this helps someone!